# Difference between a graph and a hypergraph database?

Tags: database, graph, nosql, definition

Is there a difference between a graph and a hypergraph database?

Is every hypergraph database system also a graph database system?

I am asking for a side-by-side comparison. If it is possible to show this in one row:

```
Graph support:       No/Graph/Hypergraph
```

Or if it is better to use two rows:

```
Graph support:       No/Yes
Hypergraph suppport: No/Yes
```

Or means "graph" and "hypergraph" the same in the database context?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How a certain graph database handles its edges is an implementation detail. Hence an answer cannot really be given in regards to "[hyper]graph databases in general".

From the point of mathematical graph theory however there is a difference:

- **Edges** as known from *standard* **graphs** model (directed or undirected) `1:1` connections.
- **Hyperedges** as known from **hypergraphs** model (directed or undirected) `n:n` connections.

**Graph** vs. **Hypergraph**:

> A **simple graph** can be considered a **special case of the hypergraph**, namely the **2-uniform hypergraph**. However, when stated without any qualification, an edge is always assumed to consist of at most 2 vertices, and a graph is never confused with a hypergraph.
>   <sup>([Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory#Basics))</sup>

**Undirected hyperedges**:

> A[n] [undirected] hyperedge is an edge that is allowed to take on **any number of vertices**, possibly more than 2. A graph that allows any hyperedge is called a hypergraph.
>   <sup>([Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory#Basics))</sup>

**Directed hyperedges**:

> Directed hypergraphs (Ausiello et al., 1985; Gallo et al., 1993) are a generalization of directed graphs (digraphs) and they can **model binary relations among subsets of a given set**.
>   <sup>([Source](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0101-74382005000300005))</sup>

Comment: This is not quite correct. A hypergraph is a **many to many** connection, not a **one to many** connection. ([Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph))

Comment: @Regexident I was talking about the *edges* and not the whole hypergraph. I am not so deep into this topic but I think that makes a difference? So maybe we are both right?

Comment: Nope. Undirected hyperedges are just `n` connections (`n` being a set of vertices, or `n:n` with both `n` being equal sets of vertices). While directed hyperedges are `n:n` connections (again `n` being sets of vertices).

Comment: @Regexident Would be great if you could fix my answer? (I guess it's possible because it is a "community wiki"?) My understanding seems to be not deep enough yet.